# Deployd setting up email

Tags: deployd

Hi I have a deployd application that is working fine with its dashboard localhost:2403/dashboard

I want to utilise email with the app  the deployd instructions state that I run  npm install dpd-email 
which creates a dpd-email directory in your app's node_modules directory.

To set up the emails ports etc 
Before using the email resource, you must go to its Dashboard page and configure it.

Is this the apps dashboard  as I can see no reference to email in localhost:2403/dashboard
or is there a seperate dashboard for dpd-email module ?

Answer (score 1):

After installing the dpd-email module (`npm install dpd-email`), the dashboard should propose a new type a resource:

[image: New resource Email]

After adding this new resource, you can configure the module:
[image]

You can send emails by sending requests (see [the readme](https://github.com/deployd/dpd-email) of the module for more information)